# Excel add-in is being shown as a COM add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, excel-addins

I want to build an excel add-in which is application level. I followed the instructions to create a project on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc668205.aspx).

I don't want to create a COM add-in, I want an Excel plugin. The plugin we create as .xlam file and code it in VBA.

Please suggest me what to do. How to deploy the .vsto file and patch up with the .xlam file?

Comment: _"and it shows me it as a COM add-in...I don't want to create a COM add-in i want Excel plugin"_ - sorry to pop your balloon but add-ins created via VSTO _are_ COM add-ins as far as Excel is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VSTO Office add-in *is* a COM add-in by definition. That is how Microsoft implemented it. They have built a bridge from .NET to the native Microsoft Office code using COM.

If you want an XLAM add-in, as you say, you need to go through [this reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-add-ins-64d3d147-98fb-4b82-8833-709d54e3ace1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bmexceladdin), which doesn't involve creating a Visual Studio VSTO project.

Comment: Is there any way to make the excel add-in in c# not in VBA?, because i already have vba excel add-in.

Comment: Well, yes. Create the add-in as you did from Visual Studio and code from there. There are some pretty good tutorials that helped me out. Just search Google on *VSTO C#* and you will find plenty of them (primarily the MSDN resources are useful).